# Excel VBA SHA1 function

Tags: .net, excel, vba, sha1

I'm running this module but it keeps giving me an error and the debug send me to this line:

> ```
> Set oSHA1 = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Managed")
> ```
>
> *Run-time error '-2146233079 (80131509': Automation Error)*

I added a reference to the `mscorlib` type library, but it's still not working.

```
Public Function SHA1(sIn As String, Optional bB64 As Boolean = 0) As String
    'Set a reference to mscorlib 4.0 64-bit

    'Test with empty string input:
    '40 Hex:   da39a3ee5e6...etc
    '28 Base-64:   2jmj7l5rSw0yVb...etc

    Dim oT As Object, oSHA1 As Object
    Dim TextToHash() As Byte
    Dim bytes() As Byte

    Set oT = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")
    Set oSHA1 = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Managed")

    TextToHash = oT.GetBytes_4(sIn)
    bytes = oSHA1.ComputeHash_2((TextToHash))

    If bB64 = True Then
       SHA1 = ConvToBase64String(bytes)
    Else
       SHA1 = ConvToHexString(bytes)
    End If

    Set oT = Nothing
    Set oSHA1 = Nothing

End Function
```

```
Private Function ConvToBase64String(vIn As Variant) As Variant

    Dim oD As Object

    Set oD = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
      With oD
        .LoadXML "<root />"
        .DocumentElement.DataType = "bin.base64"
        .DocumentElement.nodeTypedValue = vIn
      End With
    ConvToBase64String = Replace(oD.DocumentElement.Text, vbLf, "")

    Set oD = Nothing

End Function

Private Function ConvToHexString(vIn As Variant) As Variant

    Dim oD As Object

    Set oD = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")

      With oD
        .LoadXML "<root />"
        .DocumentElement.DataType = "bin.Hex"
        .DocumentElement.nodeTypedValue = vIn
      End With
    ConvToHexString = Replace(oD.DocumentElement.Text, vbLf, "")

    Set oD = Nothing

End Function
```

I changed this in the code

```
'Set oT = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")
'Set oSHA1 = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Managed")
With New UTF8Encoding
    TextToHash = .GetBytes_4(sIn)
End With

With New SHA1Managed
    bytes = .ComputeHash_2((TextToHash))
End With
```

And now I'm getting the same error but at With New SHA1Managed

This is how I have the code now, but still getting error at With New SHA1Managed

Public Function SHA1(sIn As String, Optional bB64 As Boolean = 0) As String
    'Set a refe

```
'Test with empty string input:
'40 Hex:   da39a3ee5e6...etc
'28 Base-64:   2jmj7l5rSw0yVb...etc

Dim oT As Object, oSHA1 As Object
'Dim TextToHash() As Byte
'Dim bytes() As Byte

'Set oT = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")
'Set oSHA1 = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Managed")
With New UTF8Encoding
    TextToHash = .GetBytes_4(sIn)
End With

With New SHA1Managed
    bytes = .ComputeHash_2((TextToHash))
End With

TextToHash = oT.GetBytes_4(sIn)
bytes = oSHA1.ComputeHash_2((TextToHash))

If bB64 = True Then
   SHA1 = ConvToBase64String(bytes)
Else
   SHA1 = ConvToHexString(bytes)
End If

Set oT = Nothing
Set oSHA1 = Nothing
```

End Function

[image: project references dialog]

I changed the reference to v2.05 mscorlib.tlb, but I'm still getting the same error

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting?

Comment: Run-time error '-2146233079 (80131509': Automation Error

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications/String_Hashing_in_VBA , this is where I found this code by the way

Comment: Since you are setting a reference to mscorlib, why are you also using late-binding?

Comment: I'd like to get past the Createobject SHA1

Comment: I'm not really understanding late-binding

Comment: In addition to @Mat'sMug explanation of late vs early binding, there are numerous articles available through an internet search.  If you are going to be doing any advanced programming in VBA, it is something you need to understand.

Answer (score 2):

If you're referencing the type library, then there's no need to use `CreateObject` to create an instance of anything in that library.

> *I'm not really understanding late-binding – Alex Mikhaylov 7 mins ago*

This is where it's happening:

> ```
> Dim oT As Object, oSHA1 As Object
> ```

By working against the `Object` interface, VBA has no compile-time knowledge of the object's members; calls against it will be *late-bound*, i.e. resolved at run-time. You don't get *IntelliSense*, and VBA will compile any typo or mistakes you make when calling its members: you'll only know at run-time that something is wrong.

*Early-binding* means you're working with types VBA knows about at compile-time: you get *IntelliSense* for everything, and VBA will refuse to compile a typo, or a member call with, say, missing non-optional parameters.

Something like this then:

```
Sub test()

    Dim inputBytes() As Byte
    With New UTF8Encoding
        inputBytes = .GetBytes_4("TEST")
    End With

    Dim outputBytes() As Byte
    With New SHA1Managed
        outputBytes = .ComputeHash_2((inputBytes))
    End With

    Debug.Print ConvToHexString(outputBytes)

End Sub
```

Notice the `With New` blocks take care of creating and destroying the object references, so you don't even need local variables for them.

---

Tested with a reference to `mscorlib.tlb` from the **.NET 2.0 framework** (works with 32 or 64 bit versions apparently) - immediate pane (Ctrl+G) output:

```
Sheet1.Test
984816fd329622876e14907634264e6f332e9fb3
```

Try removing the reference, okaying the dialog, then bring it up again and <kbd>browse</kbd> to `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727`, and select `mscorlib.tlb` (not `.dll`).

Comment: I made these changes  'Set oT = CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")
    'Set oSHA1 = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Managed")
    With New UTF8Encoding
        TextToHash = .GetBytes_4(sIn)
    End With

    With New SHA1Managed
        bytes = .ComputeHash_2((TextToHash))
    End With

Comment: Dude, the whole point of `New`ing up the objects is that you don't need to `CreateObject` them. Sorry if my answer wasn't clear enough about that... Just delete these `CreateObject` calls, and verify that you're using the correct type by looking at what's available to that mscorlib type library, in the *Object Browser* (F2).

Comment: Hey mans thanks so much for all the help, what should I do to the code

Comment: *Remove the `CreateObject` calls and the local variables*.

Comment: I updated the code, but getting same error at With New SHA1Managed

Comment: Runs perfectly fine here.